# Set permissions within create table script

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple create table script, below:

```
CREATE TABLE  [dbo].[CAS_WORKED](
    [recordid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Region] [varchar](20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [OpsLevel1] [varchar](20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [OpsLevel2] [varchar](20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [CostCentre] [varchar](4) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL

CONSTRAINT [PK_CAS_WORKED] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [recordid] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Is there a way to setup Delete, Insert, Select and Update permissions for a specific database role within the create table script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new database role and then assign rights via the following:

For example, I have a role called "Custom_Admin"

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON CAS_WORKED TO CustomAdmin

or (more standard, you should have fulluser)

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON CAS_WORKED TO FULLUSER

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible to put permissions in the same script, even in the same batch, but not possible on the same statement. The `CREATE TABLE` should be issued normally, and then the `GRANT`/`DENY` to setup permissions. For example, it can be something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test (Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) ;
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.test TO SomeUser ;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON CAS_WORKED
TO USERGROUP1, USERGROUP2;
```